# Unity InputSystem Multitap Value Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity's new input system and when I use the interaction's multi-tab, I can't get the value of the input at all, so I was wondering if it was a limitation of the input system or my own error.

Input Code:

[image: Input Code]

: num 1 input. no Multitap. (scale set 1.)
[image: InputSystem num1 Setting]

: num 2 input. Set Multitap. (scale set 2.)
[image: InputSystem num2 Setting]

Console debug

[image: Console Debug]

Input 1, which is not a multitap, outputs a normal value (scale 1), but Input 2, which is set to multitap, outputs a value of 0 (scale set 2!).

I've been looking through forums but haven't found anything relevant. Has anyone had the same experience?